# Regex in English works but a similar regex in a different language does not work

Tags: regex

Testing `12/KMY(Naing)056503` against Regex `(1[0-5]|[0-9])/[A-Z]{3}\(Naing\)[0-9]{6}` returns true but testing `၁၂/ကမရ(နိုင်)ဝ၅၆၅ဝ၃` against `(1[၀-၅]|[၀-၉])/[က-အ]{3}\(နိုင်\)[၀-၉]{6}`. Why does this happen?

This regex looks like the following in my IDE.

[image: regex]

Comment: More likely you need a unicode flag `\u`

Comment: @Kasramvd I have the flags in my code. Look at my updated question.

Comment: what host language are writing this in?

Comment: That's note the flag those are just the representation of unicode character to need a `u` as a unicode flag.what's the language you are dealing with?

Comment: The language is Myanmar (or Burmese). The mother tongue of Aung San Suu Kyi.

Comment: This is nothing too do with `(?u)`, which allows case insensitive matching (not relevant here) work for unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not matching because of two reasons:

Reason 1:
`(1[၀-၅]|[၀-၉])` should be `[၀-၅][၀-၉]`
`(1[၀-၅]|[၀-၉])` means `1` followed by a char in the range `၀-၅` OR a char in the range `၀-၉`, which is (I think) not what you meant, because `[၀-၅][၀-၉]` matches `၁၂`.

Reason 2:
`[၀-၉]{6}` doesn't match `ဝ၅၆၅ဝ၃`, because the range `၀-၉`, which is decimal `4160 - 4169`, does not include `ဝ` which is decimal `4125`.

The rest matches.

Comment: The actual regex that I have chosen to use is `([၁-၉]|၁[၀-၅])/[က-အ]{3}\(နိုင်\)[၀-၉]{6}` but you have been a great help.